# mocking formula-derived fields in Grails 2.2.1

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, spock

I have a Domain class that uses a constraint with formula to calculate several fields. The fields are nullable, but when I am unit testing, the created objects fail to save, throwing ValidationException.

When I test this same code in while running the debugger (not in unit test), the fields are null, yet there are no errors.

I feel that if I could Mock the formula to return 0, I could run the test successfully. For example: `Part.metaClass.getNumberOfObj1 = { return 0 }`. Of course, this does not work.

Is there a way to mock the mapping of a formula onto these fields so the object can be persisted? Or, if not, is there a way to modify my setup to eliminate the (weird) errors that I am getting?

The Domain Class

```
class Part extends Base {
    ...
    Long    numberOfObj1
    Long    numberOfObj2
    Long    numberOfObj3

    static hasMany = [obj1:Obj1,obj2:Obj2,obj3:Obj3]

    static mapping = {
        numberOfObj1  formula: '(select count(id) from ' + Base.defaultSchema() + '.obj_1 ob1 where (ob1.pt_id = ID and ob1.deleted = \'F\'))'
        numberOfObj2  formula: '(select count(id) from ' + Base.defaultSchema() + '.obj_2 ob2 where (ob2.pt_id = ID)'
        numberOfObj3  formula: '(select count(id) from ' + Base.defaultSchema() + '.obj_3 ob1 where (ob3.pt_id = ID )'  
    ... }  
}
```

The Unit test

```
@TestMixin(ControllerUnitTestMixin)
@TestFor(PartController)
class PartControllerSpec extends BaseTestSpec {
    def "given a part search, when the create action is called"() {
        given:
            def obj1= createObj1()
            params.number = "1"
            params.rev = "A"

        when:
            controller.create()

        then:
            //test stuff
    }
}
```

Inside controller.create()

```
def create() {
    newPart = new Part(number:params.number,
                       revision:params.rev)//fields are null here
    try{
        newPart.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        return
    }
```

The Error

```
grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation error occured during call to save():
- Field error in object 'com.Part' on field 'numberOfObj1': rejected value [null];codes [com.Part.numberOfObj1.nullable.error.com.Part.numberOfObj1,...
```

Comment: Why not just integration test?

Comment: @JamesKleeh Yes, that is always an option, but we have a desire to create Unit tests over Int test to save time during testing. Since unit test run much faster. Also, i guess I just get obsessed with making it work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `nullable: true` constraint to this field. That's what I did.

See also [Grails3 unit test for domain class with derived property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945824/grails3-unit-test-for-domain-class-with-derived-property)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat better solution is the following

```
static constraints = {
    if (Environment.current == Environment.TEST) {
        derivedField(nullable: true)
    }
}
```

This way you won't have to deal with `Derived properties may not be constrained` startup warnings