# Grails3 unit test for domain class with derived property

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I have the following Domain class with [derived property](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties) `lowercaseTag`.

```
class Hashtag {
    String tag
    String lowercaseTag

    static mapping = {
        lowercaseTag formula: 'lower(tag)'
    }
}
```

If I run the following unit test, it will fail on the last line, because `lowercaseTag` property is `null` and by default all properties have `nullable: false` constraint.

```
@TestFor(Hashtag)
class HashtagSpec extends Specification {
    void "Test that hashtag can not be null"() {
        when: 'the hashtag is null'
        def p = new Hashtag(tag: null)

        then: 'validation should fail'
        !p.validate()

        when: 'the hashtag is not null'
        p = new Hashtag(tag: 'notNullHashtag')

        then: 'validation should pass'
        p.validate()
    }
}
```

The question is how to properly write unit tests in such cases? Thanks!

Comment: How come the property is named `lowercaseTag` yet the formula is being defined for the non-existent property `lowercase`?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa sorry, typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm sure you've figured out, the `lowercaseTag` cannot be tested because it's database dependent; Grails unit tests do not use a database, so the formula/expression is not evaluated.

I think the best option is to modify the constraints so that `lowercaseTag` is nullable.

```
class Hashtag {
    String tag
    String lowercaseTag

    static mapping = {
        lowercaseTag formula: 'lower(tag)'
    }

    static constraints = {
        lowercaseTag nullable: true
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to modify the test to force `lowercaseTag` to contain *some* value so that `validate()` works.

```
p = new Hashtag(tag: 'notNullHashtag', lowercaseTag: 'foo')
```

Comment: Another option is to write that test with a `@HibernateTestMixin`, which will run the unit test against an H2-database.